# .npm directory consumes 149+ GB of disc space

Tags: jenkins, npm

The .npm folder inside /var/lib/jenkins/ consumes 149 GB of disc space ,
Can you help me to find the RC and am i able to clean any of the content inside .npm directory to find some disc space

Answer (score 0):

Clearing npm cache can reduce the size of the .npm directory. Run npm cache clean --force in your build steps where required and see the difference.

If it is a declarative pipeline you're using add a build step in your NPM stage like this.

```
            stage('NPM installation') {
                 steps {
                     container("tools") {
                         sh """
                         npm install
                         npm cache clean --force
                         """
                     }
                 }
             }
```

More details on npm cache clean can be found here --> [NPM-Cache-Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html)